# Output all command line parameters

Tags: c#, command-line

I am working on a console application, that receives a pretty long list of parameters. For debugging purpose I need to print the parameters passed to a an output file. Right now, I am using the following code to concat command line parameters.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string Params = string.Empty;
    foreach(string arg in args)
    {
       Params += arg + ",";
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this piece of code

```
String.Join(", ", Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
```

Answer (score 6):

What about

```
Params = string.Join(",", args);
```

Your `foreach` approach is not very performant. Since a string is *immutable*, that means for each iteration of the loop, the string will get thrown away for garbage collection, and a new string will be generated. In the `string.Join` case, only one string will be generated.

Inside the loop, to get around the same performance, you will have to use a `StringBuilder`, but in this case it's really no reason not to use `string.Join` since the code will be much more readable.

Comment: +1 - Also, string.Join does not leave a trailing comma on the joined string, as the original code does (I assume that's a good thing for @cbyte's purpose)

Comment: I prefere using blank space separator like in original comman line       Params = string.Join(" ", args);

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.Join(",",args)

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers here combining the arguments with a single comma will work, but I found that approach lacking somewhat because there's not a clear indicator of "quoted arguments" and those that might contain a comma.

Using the example: `Foo.exe an example "is \"fine\", too" okay`

The simple join suggestions will yield: `an, example, is "fine", too, okay`.  Not bad, but not very clear and somewhat misleading.

Here's what I threw together that works well enough for me.  I'm sure it could be improved further.

```
String.Join(", ", (from a in args select '"' + a.Replace("\"", @"\""") + '"'));
```

It returns the string: `"an", "example", "is \"fine\", too", "okay"`. I think this does a better job indicating the actual parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
String params = String.Join(",", args);
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but this wont compile. *params* is a keyword in C#. You will have to select another name for your string :)

Comment: auch, I Just lower cased cbyte's variable name because of convention :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
string.Join(",", args);
```

Strictly speaking the Join function creates a StringBuilder with capacity strings.Length * 16 (this 16 is a fixed number). If you have different args maximum size and if performance is crucial to you, use a StringBuilder with a specific capacity.